# Construction of i.i.d random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Is it possible to construct i.i.d random variables $X_i : \Omega_1 \to \Omega_2$, $1 \leq i \leq n$, when $\Omega_1$ is a finite set? If so, is there a general 
method for such a construction?

Thanks,
Phanindra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the measure space consists of finitely many atoms, you have only a finite-dimensional space of functions on these atoms, and thus the number of non-constant independent random variables you can have is certainly bounded (you can have as many constant random variables as you have possible values, and constants are always independent).  $n$ independent random variables, each taking at least $2$ possible values, requires at least $2^n$ possible $n$-tuples of values, so
$2^n$ atoms.  Given those $2^n$ atoms $\omega_0, \ldots, \omega_{2^n-1}$, you can define $n$ independent random variables with values $0$ and $1$ as follows:
each atom has probability $2^{-n}$, and $X_j(\omega_k)$ is the $j$'th binary digit of 
$k$.

Comment: Robert: Thanks for the nice answer. The construction is surprising for me but very nice.